# Search across site collection for multiple keywords

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

Need to setup a search based on the keywords which can search across multiple site collection in SharePoint Online.

Is there a way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hub site to achieve this. Then associate these sites with the hub site.

When you search from a SharePoint hub site, content on the hub site itself along with content on any associated sites is returned in the search results.

References:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-sharepoint-hub-site-fe26ae84-14b7-45b6-a6d1-948b3966427f

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-hub-site

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/associate-a-sharepoint-site-with-a-hub-site-ae0009fd-af04-4d3d-917d-88edb43efc05